# Reac/Next(13) Server/Client Components Props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, next.js

каким образом можно из клиентского компонента передать состояние в родительский серверный компонент или из серверного передать в дочерний клиентский, изменить там?

Условно скажем, на сервере я загружаю данные, на клиентском есть форма поиска, как мне передать/получить состояние?